# How to execute Apple Script when click on HTML link?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, applescript

I tried to embedded apple script in a link in HTML, but all it does is brought up the Apple Script Editor Application with profiled script in it.

I want it to **execute** after I click on the link - so I don't have to press the **play** button.

Can someone help me fix this real quick ?

`link.html`

```
<a href = " 

applescript://com.apple.scripteditor?
action=new&script=

tell application %22Safari%22%0D%09
make new document with properties {URL:%22https://www.google.com%22}%0D%09 

end tell "> 

Click me to run the script ! 

</a>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That is dependent on the user's browser / operating system.  How a mac chooses to open a file is completely up to it, and to my knowledge, there's nothing you can do about it in code.

Comment: Are you trying to say that - what I am trying to do is impossible ?

Comment: I'm saying that you can probably do it on your own computer, but I don't think you can do it for anyone else's computer.

Comment: I see. Even if for my own computer, do you know how to make it run ?

Comment: It can be done.  I did it a while back for mac users.  It was necessary to first have the applescript installed on the client's machine.  If you google how to  do it, you'll find examples.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/

Answer (score 1):

You'll find your answer to your question [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/).

You'll also want to install the  RCDefaults preference pane.

You have to use the full protocol, with the '?' and all that, in order to make your own protocol work as expected. You have to follow the scheme, or whatever that is called, for that kind of requests. The linktrigger demo at MaxOsXAutomation.com, worked for me, within the last month.